# Laravel , Composer and Curl installation on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, curl

I have a Linux Mint machine I am working on. I want to install Laravel on it.

When I searched for this I got this command: `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php from "https://getcomposer.org/download/"` to put in terminal but it gives me this:

```
The program 'php' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
The program 'curl' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install curl
```

After that I have done `sudo apt-get install curl`

```
libcurl3 curl
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main libcurl3 i386 7.27.0-1ubuntu1.9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main libcurl3 i386 7.27.0-1ubuntu1.9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main curl i386 7.27.0-1ubuntu1.9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl3_7.27.0-1ubuntu1.9_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.27.0-1ubuntu1.9_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

got this which is not successfully installed `curl`

How can any one I successfully install these things and Composer and Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of Ubuntu you are using (Quantal, 12.10) is [no longer supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Table_of_versions) since May 16th. So you can no longer download packages for it.

You might be able to install `curl` and `php` from an installation DVD, or alternatively use `wget` to download the sources for both and compile them from source.

I recommend however that you upgrade (or downgrade) to a supported Ubuntu version (14.04, 12.04) as you are missing security upgrades if you stay on 12.10

Comment: Thanks @Anthon for give you time.how can i now upgrade my machine with kept my existing data in it so that i am unable to use latest packages.PLease help me

Comment: Anthon van der Neut Sir Can you help me out to upgrade my machine with new release...?

Comment: @user2640758 Have you installed 12.10 yourself? You should make a backup of your data, preferably a dump of your whole disc (on a USB drive e.g.) and then either install 14.04. You can upgrade, keeping accounts and data, but if something goes wrong, you should have a backup of at least your own data. So first backup, then download 14.04, then upgrade, and if there are problems come back here or on [Ask Ubuntu] with questions.